# Ulimit is set on second login, not first

Tags: debian, pam, ulimit

I'm using Debian Jessie and I have a strange error connected with setting the limit of open files per process.
I want to increase the default limit for certain user (me), so I added to `/etc/security/limit.conf`:

```
freyja          soft    nofile          2048
freyja          hard    nofile          2048
```

I also added to `/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

Now the limit is increased, but only when I log in the second time. 
For example, I log into my computer (using slim) after turning it on and I get:

```
freyja@host01:~$ ulimit -n
256
```

Then I log out (using i3 exit) and log in again (using slim) and I get:

```
freyja@host01:~$ ulimit -n
2048
```

The same would be if after first login I do `sudo su freyja`. Then logged with su I also get limit of `2048`.

Do you have an idea what I should change or could check to make the limit `2048` already during first login?

**Edit**:

If I raise limit for all users then it works at my first login (this is of course not a satisfactory solution):

```
*          soft    nofile          2048
*          hard    nofile          2048
```

So it looks like limit system does not recognize it's me at first login. This is very strange.

Comment: What happens if you login to a TTY first?

Comment: I commented lines with wildcard (`*`), rebooted, logged to tty1, I got `2048`. I logged via slim, got `2048`. Rebooted, logged via slim, got `2048`. Now I get `2048` after every boot, without need to log to tty1. Don't know why it started to work, because the setup is the same as before, but thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm voting
   to close this question as off-topic because the problem is no longer
   reproducible and the question is not likely to be useful for future
   visitors

Comment: Well, it stopped working again... I don't understand this. Can changes to `limits.conf`, be applied with a delay (few-reboot delay)?